# xjc does not add @XmlElement(nillable=false) on generated fields

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2, xjc, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I have a problem with generating classes using xjc. In the schema I have nillable="false", yet this is not added as an annotation (@XmlElement(nillable=false)) on the generated fields. This causes Jackson not to remove the fields when they are empty.
If I change to nillable=true, the classes are updated to reflect that as expected...

Any ideas?

Comment: `nillable` is false by default (i.e. `@XmlElement(nillable=false)` and `@XmlElement()` are identical).

Comment: Jackson is not a JAXB (JSR-222) compliant implementation.  There are no guarantees how it will interpret any standard JAXB annotation.

Comment: I guess that's what I'm facing. If I manually add XmlElement(nillable=false) to the generated source files, then Jackson works as expected... So for Jackson @XmlElement(nillable=false) is not the same as @XmlElement()

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up writing my own plugin for maven-jaxb2-plugin which checks the attributes and adds missing `@XmlElement(nillable = false)`.